# I get a system.string value error in Endpoint?

Tags: serenity-platform

I am doing the operations on the link"https://github.com/serenity-is/Serenity/issues/2614", but the end point string in the end point sends a value, but the room gives an error. What could be the reason? I would be glad if you could help.

[image]

```
        var linkButton = {
                title: Q.text("Dialogs.BulkLinkPGwithWS.Button.Link"),
                cssClass: 'link-button',
                onClick: () => {

                    if (this.form.fr.value == 0) {
                        Q.warning(Q.text("Dialogs.BulkLinkPGwithWS.Button.Link2"));
                    }
                    else {
                        Q.defaultNotifyOptions.positionClass = "toast-top-center";
                        Q.defaultNotifyOptions.newestOnTop = false;
                        Q.notifyWarning(Q.text("Dialogs.BulkPQwithWSLinkin.InProgress"), Q.text("Dialogs.BulkLink.PQwithWS.Toast.Title"));

                        var servicecall = ArsivOnayService.BulkLinkPQwithWSaction(
                            {
                                //SecilenId: this.selectedItems,
                                dene: this.selectedItems,
                                DegisecekVeri: this.form.KurulTarihi.value
                                
                            },
                            response => {
                                let options: ToastrOptions = Q.defaultNotifyOptions;
                                options.tapToDismiss = false;

                                this.dialogClose();

                                var message = JSON.parse(servicecall.responseText);
                                Q.notifySuccess(message, Q.text("Dialogs.BulkLink.Toast.Title"), options);

                            },
                            {
                                blockUI: true,
                                onError: response => {
                                    let options: ToastrOptions = Q.defaultNotifyOptions;
                                    options.timeOut = 15000;
                                    options.extendedTimeOut = 3000;

                                    this.dialogClose();
                                    Q.notifyError(Q.text("Dialogs.BulkLink.Toast.Error"), Q.text("Dialogs.BulkLink.Toast.Title"), options);
                                    var errorcontent = JSON.parse(servicecall.responseText);

                                    var message = errorcontent["Error"]["Message"]

                                    Q.alert(message);

                                },
                                //onCleanup: () => this.serviceCallCleanup()
                            });
                    }

                }

            };



   public string BulkLinkPQwithWSaction(IUnitOfWork uow, BulkLinkPQwithWSactionRequest request)
        {

            
            request.CheckNotNull();

            var error = false;

            var count_new = 0;
            var count_existing = 0;

            if (error)
                throw new ValidationError("An error occured");

            var linkrow = new ArsivOnayRow();
            var connection = SqlConnections.NewFor<ArsivOnayRow>();

          

            foreach (var x in request.dene)
            {

                var SQLCommand = "UPDATE" + linkrow.Table + " SET kurul_tarihi='" + request.DegisecekVeri + "' , Olusturma_tarihi='2019-12-28' WHERE id in (" + x+")";
                connection.Execute(SQLCommand);
                              
                if (false)
                {
                   
                }
                else
                {
                    // *** Link already exists. Skip this one ***
                    count_existing++;
                    continue;
                }

            }
            
            var returnvalue = "";

            returnvalue += string.Format(LocalText.Get("İşlem Tamamlandı"), count_new.ToString(), count_existing.ToString());

            return returnvalue;
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Serenity.RetrieveResponse<string>` as return type in your Endpoint.cs